# Survey 123 Connect Feature Service URL

Tags: feature-service, mobile-gis, arcgis-survey123

Has anyone played around with the Feature Service URL in Survey 123 Connect? There appears to be a feature service URL section under Data in the form Settings. I don't see any documentation on this function. Has anyone tried using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that in theory you could use it to manually match a feature service to your survey, but in practice you should never do so as it's impossible to maintain fidelity with the survey as it changes. Instead use Survey Gizmo to create the feature service. Personally I'd expect there to be a high probability that it will disappear in a future release.

Answer (score 2):

The Feature Service URL is meant to let you build a Survey123 form on top of an existing Hosted Feature Service.  The best way to build surveys on top of existing feature services is as follows:

1) Open Survey123 Connect and login with your ArcGIS credentials

2) Tap on Create New Survey and choose the option **Feature Service**
[image: Create Survey from Feature Service]
Note: If you do not see this option install the [latest version of Survey123 Connect for ArcGIS](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/download/)
The gallery will show now all non-public feature services shared with your account.

3) Select the source feature service  and give your survey a name. Survey123 Connect  will create a new XLS file and set the Feature Service  URL accordingly for you.

4) Tweak the XLSFile to your liking and publish the survey

As of Survey123 version 1.10, you can only work with Hosted Feature Services, although supporting Federated Services is planned.